# Conflict: conflict between User.ReadBasic.All in microsoft graph api and Report.Read.All from power bi with the same authed token

Tags: php, powerbi, microsoft-graph-api

I hope I will be able to explain this properly, I am trying to make an app in PHP that gets the authed users Power BI reports as embed.

So far I have figured out how to get the reports through the microsoft graph api, by using the following scopes "openid profile offline_access [https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/Report.Read.All"](https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/Report.Read.All%22)

This gives me a list of the users reports by calling: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports

My problem occurs when I try to get some information about the authed user: id,displayName,mail.

I figured out I needed to add: User.ReadBasic.All to the scope parameters and with this I am able to get the users: id,displayName,mail If I call /me.

But if I then call https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports after having added User.ReadBasic.All I get an 403 Forbidden in the reports call.

I hope it makes sense, my english is not always the best.

[image: These are the scopes I set in the azure portal for the app]

[image: This is the code, the /me part is outcommented as they conflict.]

Comment: I might have figured out a workaround, will post how if it works out

Answer (score 0):

Okay, did not work, so I am still lost on how to make this work.